# Laravel 5.7, advanced where or and loop dilemma

Tags: php, laravel, loops, parameters, grouping

I need to produce sql like this:

```
...where (col1 like '%a1%' or col2 like '%a1%') and (col1 like '%a2%' or col2 like '%a2%') and ...... and (col1 like '%an%' or col2 like '%an%')
```

And I know I can use "Parameter Grouping" to do this,

```
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('col1', 'like', '%a1%')
        ->orWhere('col2', 'like', '%a1%');
})
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('col1', 'like', '%a2%')
        ->orWhere('col2', 'like', '%a2%');
})
......
```

but how can I loop this? because the parameter in is a json array something like "[a1,a2,...,an]",

```
foreach ()
{
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('col1', 'like', '%an%')
            ->orWhere('col2', 'like', '%an%');
    })
}
->get;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something Like this should work,

```
$listing = Listing:where('id', $id);
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
     $i++;
     // ->where('field_1', red_1); // Desired output
     $listing->where("where(field_{$i},".$value."_1)");
}
$results = $listing->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a foreach loop inside of the closure using your array (I'm calling it $data), and assuming you are using MySQL, you can use concat to combine col1 and col2 and then use a raw query (I also used coalesce in case you have any null values in your table).

```
->where(function ($query) use ($data) {
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $query->whereRaw("concat(coalesce(`col1`, ''), ' ', coalesce(`col2`, '')) like ?", ['%'.$value.'%']);
    }
})
->get();
```

Comment: This is working for me. By using this, "like ?", ['%'.$value.'%'], can it prevent sql injection?

Comment: Yes it should - see this article: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#running-queries

Comment: You should also be able to do something like this if you don't want to use concat and coalesce.  I think it will end up with the same results.
`$query->whereRaw("(col1 like ? or col2 like ?)", ['%'.$value.'%', '%'.$value.'%']);`